# Select unique records and insert into another table avoiding duplicates in it

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have two table(userfrom and userto).

i want to insert data from "userfrom" table to "userto" and want to implement condition on two column i.e "username" and "date".

Basically i am pasting my data from "userfrom" to table "userto".

Condition before insertion is.

Same "username" with same "date" should not get inserted.
There can be same username but date shold be different.

Only username is identical in between both the tables

Please Note:(On re-run of insert query i dont want same data to be duplicated. This insert query runs for 5 time in 30 min bracket)
Table `userfrom`:

```
1 sampleusername  2017-12-04
2 sampleusername  2017-12-04
3 sampleusername2 2017-12-04
4 sampleusername  2017-12-05
```

Table `usertto`:

```
1 sampleusername  2017-12-04
2 sampleusername2 2017-12-04
3 sampleusername  2017-12-05
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, before / after versions. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Table userfrom
1 sampleusername 2017-12-04
2 sampleusername 2017-12-04
3 sampleusername2 2017-12-04

Table usertto
1 sampleusername 2017-12-04
2 sampleusername2 2017-12-04

Comment: Please edit your question with your comment so it can be formatted properly with the sample data set.

Comment: just did please check

Comment: The fact that you did not include your current query attempt makes it look like you didn't do much work on this before coming here to ask for help.

Comment: answers given below are not helping because if i re-run the insert query it will duplicate the whole data again

Comment: @VipulDubey - Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eeed685/5)

You can use [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) and [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql) in sql server like below :

```
insert into userto (username, date)
select distinct username, date from userfrom uf
where 
not exists(select 1 from userto where username=uf.username and date=uf.date)
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: I used it as an alternative as you used `distinct` already, both produces same result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the two tables, and then only insert the values from userfrom that don't exist in userto table like this:

```
INSERT INTO userTo
    (
        username
        ,userDate
    )
SELECT DISTINCT f.username
      ,f.userDate
FROM usertrom f
LEFT JOIN userto t ON f.username = t.username AND f.userDate = t.userDate
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```